# Solve $x'=x^nt^m$ for any $m,n\in\mathbb R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve by separating variabels **for all** $m,n,x_0\in\mathbb R$:
>
> $x'(t)=x(t)^nt^m, x(0)=x_0$

I am wondering how to *interpret* this question. If $m\in\mathbb Z$ and $m<0$, I'd assume the question means to solve $t^{-m}x'(t)=x(t)^n$, because then the differential equation is defined for $t=0$. However, I'm not sure what to do in the case $m$ is irrational, say $m=\sqrt{2}$. Then $t^m=e^{m\ln(t)}$ is not defined for $t\leq 0$, and the equation cannot be rewritten in a form such that it is defined at $t=0$.

Or would the simple answer be: for $m<0$ or $m\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ there are no solutions, because the differential equation is not defined at $t=0$ in those cases?

Comment: Could it be that it is meant to be solved for $t>0$ only? It does have the structure of an initial value problem (given the initial value at $t=0$).

Comment: @DominikS That would seem odd to me given the initial value at $t=0$.

Comment: Why, that would be exactly the structure: $x(0)= x_0$ would be the initial value at $t=0$. The IVP would be "Solve $x'(t) =\ldots$ for $t\ge0$, provided the initial condition $x(0) = x_0$".

Comment: @DominikS Ah, I see what you mean now. So at $t=0$ the solution doesn't need to satisfy the ODE (because the ODE is not defined there), but for $t>0$ it has to satisfy it, and additionally we want $x(0)=x_0$. OK, that is sensible

Comment: Yes, at least that would be my interpretation of it. :)